# Can we use Fragments for using number of activities within a single activities that runs concurrently

Tags: android, android-fragments

Is it possible to use fragments for number of activities within a single activities which runs concurrently.i want to know that if fragments is same as activity.If i will use fragments Can it serve my purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fragments are not as activities. And they won't let you do what you want. I will repeat my self: use Services or AsyncTasks.

As for Fragments, they are more like reusable views.